# xpath not extracting all fields

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Im trying to retrieve all the data from a html output with the following code:

```
proxy_auth = "http://"+proxyUser+":"+proxyPass+"@"+proxyHost
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": proxy_auth})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

request = urllib2.Request("http://"+iserver+"/invoke/pub.art/listRegisteredAdapters")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (login, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()

doc = LH.fromstring(html)
tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath("//td"))

print html

for td, val in zip(*[tds]*2):
    if td == "adapterTypeName" :

        adapterTypeName=val
        print adapterTypeName
```

This is the original html output,

```
<BODY bgcolor=#dddddd>
<TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>registeredAdapterList</B></TD>
<TD>
<TABLE>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>adapterTypeName</B></TD>
<TD>SAPAdapter</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>adapterTypeName</B></TD>
<TD>SMSCAdapter</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>adapterTypeName</B></TD>
<TD>PRTServerAdapter</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>adapterTypeName</B></TD>
<TD>com.vf.bdp.BDPAdapter</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>adapterTypeName</B></TD>
<TD>SiebelAdapter</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><TABLE bgcolor=#dddddd border=1>
<TR>
<TD valign="top"><B>adapterTypeName</B></TD>
<TD>JDBCAdapter</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
```

What i was expecting was to retrieve the following fields:

```
SAPAdapter
SMSCAdapter
PRTServerAdapter
com.vf.bdp.BDPAdapter
SiebelAdapter
JDBCAdapter
```

Instead , im only receiving:

```
SMSCAdapter
com.vf.bdp.BDPAdapter
JDBCAdapter
```

Since im new to Python, i dont know what can be could be wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the xpath expression, which is too permissive.
It's finding elements you don't actually want to find.
Try printing the results to see what I'm talking about.

It seems to me you want to find the text all the td elements which contain no children elements.
A simple way to do that is:

```
doc = LH.fromstring(html)
for td in doc.xpath('//td[not(*)]/text()'):
    print td
```